# Writing ROR API only wrapper for existing APIs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I have a running java application which has some APIs, but none of them follow the REST standards. You need to use separate APIs(some are XML/JSON based and others are SMTP based) to achieve CRUS operations.

I really love the MVC architecture and the strict **REST**fullness of ROR, so I am thinking to write a API only ROR service using [rails-api](https://github.com/spastorino/rails-api) gem. Is it recommended to write wrappers like this over the existing APIs to provide better REST APIs?

Note: The existing APIs are very old and I don't want to rewrite them from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not it's "recommended" depends on your needs, your timeframe, the ROI, etc. There's nothing *wrong* with writing a RESTful layer over existing APIs, if that's what you're really asking.

I prefer a "regular" API over one that has multiple access methods, irregular access patterns, etc. If I have the time and resources, putting a layer of abstraction over complexity is almost always valuable.

Comment: >>There's nothing wrong with writing a RESTful layer over existing APIs, if that's what you're really asking. Yes. Since I don't have much timeframe I plan to put a RESTfull API layer, which handles the old "not so good" API.